# How to map values between JS objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How to map values of one object to other if keys matched, trying to assign values here `additionalData.value =userParams[prop] ? userParams[prop] : '';` however it pushing empty string any idea what has implemented wrong here ? or any better approach to achieve this task

```js
const getParams = (userParams) => {
    const interactionData = [];
    const interactionDataDict  = {
        firstName: [{key: "FIRST_NAME", defaultValue: null}],
        lastName: [{key: "LAST_NAME", defaultValue: null}],
        SourceSystem: [{key: "SOURCE_SYSTEM", defaultValue: null}]
    };
    for (const prop in interactionDataDict) {
        if (prop) {
            for (const val of interactionDataDict[prop]) {
                const additionalData = {};
                additionalData.key = val.key;
                if (val.defaultValue) {
                    additionalData.value = val.defaultValue;
                }
                else {
                    additionalData.value =
                        userParams[prop] ? userParams[prop] : '';
                }
                interactionData.push(additionalData);
            }
        }
    }
    return interactionData;
}

const args = { 
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Hayne",
    sourceSystem: "HTS"
}

console.log(getParams(args))
```

expected output

```
[{"key":"FIRST_NAME","value":"John"},{"key":"LAST_NAME","value":"Hayne"},{"key":"SOURCE_SYSTEM","value":"HTS"}]
```

Comment: why has `interactionDataDict` arrays?

Comment: It looks as though there's a typo in `interationDataDict`.  Why is the key `SourceSystem` capitalized and the others are not.  If you change, this, I think your problem goes away.

Comment: to have pre assignment for the default value as null i had to create interationDataDict as an array

Comment: @hussain: The point is why is `interactionDataDict.firstName` the single-element array `[{key: "FIRST_NAME", defaultValue: null}]` instead of the plain object `{key: "FIRST_NAME", defaultValue: null}`?

Comment: never thought of this it may be easier with plain object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the entries and get key and value for the new objects.

```js
function getParams(userParams) {
    const interactionDataDict = { firstName: [{ key: "FIRST_NAME", defaultValue: null }], lastName: [{ key: "LAST_NAME", defaultValue: null }], SourceSystem: [{ key: "SOURCE_SYSTEM", defaultValue: null }] }; 
    return Object
        .entries(interactionDataDict)
        .map(([k, [{ key, defaultValue }]]) =>
            ({ key, value: userParams[k] || defaultValue })
        );
}

const args = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Hayne", sourceSystem: "HTS" }

console.log(getParams(args));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you simplify this it is throwing alot of errors with es6 code i guess

Comment: @hussain: what environment are you running in that ES6 doesn't work?

Comment: @ScottSauyet gettign this error Type 'unknown' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488

Comment: @Nina: Note, though, that if `interactionDataDict` is really local to this function (instead of an additional parameter or something in a higher scope), you might as well store it as the *result* of that `Object.entries` call, something like `[['firstName', {key: ... defaultValue: ...}], ['lastName', {...}], ...]`, and then have the function consist only of the `map` call.

Comment: @ScottSauyet that might be the issue `interactionDataDict` is not local to this function it is private attribute of the class , i added in the question in local scope to better understand instead of adding class code but even after changing to `this. interactionDataDict` it didn't work

Comment: @hussain: then you might try replacing `Object.entries(interactionDataDict)` with `Object.entries(this.interactionDataDict)` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer independently, but ended up with the same logical solution as Nina.  But I structured it somewhat differently, and it might be of interest:

```js
const buildDefaults = (dict) => (args) => 
  Object 
    .entries (dict)
    .map (([k, [{key, defaultValue}]]) => ({key, value: args [k] || defaultValue}))


const getParams = buildDefaults ({
  firstName: [{key: "FIRST_NAME", defaultValue: null}],
  lastName: [{key: "LAST_NAME", defaultValue: null}],
  sourceSystem: [{key: "SOURCE_SYSTEM", defaultValue: null}]
})

const args = { 
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Hayne",
  sourceSystem: "HTS"
}

console .log (getParams (args))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here we write the generic function `buildDefaults` that takes the dictionary and returns a function that takes `args` and fills in your output the way you want.  Then `getParams` is created by calling it with your dictionary.

If, as discussed in the comments, you wanted to remove the array wrappers in the dictionary, so that it looks like this:

```js
{
    firstName: {key: "FIRST_NAME", defaultValue: null},
    lastName: {key: "LAST_NAME", defaultValue: null},
    sourceSystem: {key: "SOURCE_SYSTEM", defaultValue: null}
}
```

then you could just replace it in the destructured parameter by replacing this line:

```js
    .map (([k, [{key, defaultValue}]]) => ({key, value: args [k] || defaultValue}))
```

with this:

```js
    .map (([k, {key, defaultValue}]) => ({key, value: args [k] || defaultValue}))
```

Comment: i think its just this line if you can help how do i map userParams instead of writing complex code  `additionalData.value =
             eci[prop] ? eci[prop] : userParams[prop] ? userParams[prop] : '';` in my orginal code

Comment: @hussain: I don't know what that is.  `eci`?  My answer and Nina's answer both seem to do what you need.  But my first comment on the question shows the smallest change to get this working.  I find either of the answers much simpler than your code, so we have very different ideas about "complex code".  Sorry.